# Как сложить результаты массивов php

Tags: php, html, css, mysql, массивы

Всем привет, помогите пожалуйста
В бд хранится таблица в которой  несколько данных с определенным ид
Я хотел бы получить все и сложить в одно число

```
$get_player_resource = $link->query("SELECT * FROM `player_resource_gather` WHERE `player_id` = '$player_id'"); 
foreach($get_player_resource as $resource){
    $get_resource = intval($resource['amount']);
    var_dump($get_resource);
    
}
```

на выходе получаю два числа
int(7) int(290)

их будет более, как бы сделать результат из этих двух 297?

Comment: Сразу получать в запросе сумму, а не тянуть по отдельности и потом морщить мозг, как бы их сложить,

Comment: @Akina может ему все данные нужны, и в конце итог подсчитать )

Comment: `$get_resource +=` если остальные данные тоже нужны, и `select sum(..)` если нужна только сумма.

Comment: @teran Ну тогда GROUP BY WITH ROLLUP. Нахрена всё тащить на клиента и там потом сопли жевать?